# CSS: how to "plot" invisible text over an image?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a webpage containing a 200x200 image. At coordinates 50,50,150,150 (x1, y1, x2, y2), say I have the letter "A".

How do I do the following in CSS:

1. Overlay the image with the character "A" starting at the coordinates x1, y1?
2. Size the text such that it fits x1, y1, x2, y2?
3. Make the text invisible (but still on "top" of the image so that it can be selected)?

Also, say that this image can be moved by the user (e.g. via drag and drop). How would I maintain the position of the overlaid text?

Comment: If you must use coordinates image map is the best solution... Even if you can move the image, the coordinates will remain same (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an absolute positioned wrapper, we can use an `img` tag to add in the image, then use a `span` to contain the overlaid text, like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="image.png" alt="" />
    <span id="text">A</span>
</div>
```

**Part one** is easy: by absolute positioning the `span` inside the relative positioned wrapper, we can move the `span` into the correct position:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper #text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

**Part two** is a little stranger. The problem is that with fonts, a `font-size` of 100px isn't actually going to cause the font to fill the box of 100px height. You will have to experiment to find the correct font size. However, we **can** resize the `span` so that it is 50px wide and 50px high:

```
#wrapper #text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Adding an `border` will show that the span has the correct size, and that the letter is centered both vertically and horizontally.

Lastly, **part three** is simple *if* we're only targeting modern browsers here. Using a rgba color with zero opacity, we can make the text invisible and selectable at the same time.

```
#wrapper #text {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

**Bonus: Making the thing draggable.** By dropping in [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), we can easily make the box draggable. Adding in a `cancel` option so that the text remain selectable, and we're done!

```
$('#wrapper').draggable({
    cancel: '#text'
});
```

**See it all coming together here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/83W7X/**

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem and I've seen that this solution does the trick except for that when text is selected, it's visible.  Is there any way to make selected text (though not selection itself) invisible?

Comment: You can try setting the [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A%3Aselection) pseudo-element's `color` property to `transparent`

Comment: Grand! Excellent feedback, +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you set the image as a background to a `span`, `div`, or other container element (whatever is appropriate for the content and its purpose on your page), and then use padding to 
position the character within the container.  Size the text by setting `font-size` on the container, and then use `text-indent: -999999px` to make the text hidden.

The position of the text would stay the same when the containing element is moved, because the position is relative to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Using canvas set the background image first. Then using the following method

```
void fillText(in DOMString text, in float x, in float y, [optional] in float maxWidth);
```

set the Text on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

Just create an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

example (*with a letter :)*) at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/dKuBc/